# value of $d$ in $3$ dimensional Geometry

Tags: 3d

> The point $P(1,2,3)$ is reflected in the $x-y$ plane, Then its image $Q$ is rotated by $180^\circ$ about the $x$ axis to produce $R$, finally $R$ is translated in the direction of positive $y$ axis through the distance $d$ to produce $S(1,3,3)$. Then $d$ is

Try: Coordinate of $Q$ is $(1,2,-3)$. Now  i did not understand How can i rotate $180^\circ$ about $x$ axis. Could some help me, thanks

Comment: Think about what $180^\circ$ around the $x$-axis means specifically in the $yz$-plane. Then extrapolate.

Answer (score 1):

If you rotate about $x$-axis, you keep the $x$-value fixed, and flip the sign of the $y$ and $z$ coordinate.

Hence $R$ is $(1, -2, 3)$.

Hopefully you can compute $d$ from here.